# json_encode multiple arrays into one JSON object in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm new to php and am trying to encode 2 arrays together into one JSON object.

Currently this is the JSON output:

```
{
    "image_link": "some url",
    "zoomin_level": "8",
    "zoomout_level": "18.5",
    "position_lat": "32.913105",
    "position_long": "-117.140363",
}
```

What I like to achieve is the following:

```
{
    "image_link": "some url",
    "zoomin_level": "2",
    "zoomout_level": "15",
    "position_lat": "32.9212",
    "position_long": "-117.124",

    "locations": {
        "1": {
            "image_link": "some url",
            "name": "Name",
            "lat": 32.222,
            "marker_long": -112.222
        },
        "2": {
            "image_link": "some url",
            "name": "Name",
            "lat": 32.222,
            "marker_long": -112.222
        }
    }
}
```

This is similar to the question asked here: [PHP json_encode multiple arrays into one object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684084/php-json-encode-multiple-arrays-into-one-object)

However mine is a bit different because I like to add the 2nd array as part of a key-value part within the 1st array.

Here's my php code:

```
$sql = "select * from first_table";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting "    . mysqli_error($connection));

$rowCount = $result->num_rows;
$index = 1  ;
$newArray = [];
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $sqlnew = "select * from second_table";
    $resultnew = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlnew) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //create an array
    $jsonData = array();
    $rowCountnew = $resultnew->num_rows;
    $indexnew = 1;

    if ($rowCountnew >0)
    {
        while($rownew =mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultnew))
        {
            $locations[$indexnew] = array("image_link" => $rownew['image_link'], "name" => $rownew['name'], "position_lat" => doubleval($rownew['position_lat']), "position_long" => doubleval($rownew['position_long']) );

            ++$indexnew;

        }   
    }
    $newArray[$row['map_type']] = $row['map_value'];
}

echo json_encode($newArray);
```

Not knowing the proper syntax, I tried to perform the following which resulted in garbage: `echo json_encode($newArray, "locations" =>$locations);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$newArray['locations'] = $locations;
echo json_encode ($newArray);
```

Comment: one last question, is there any way to change the auto-generated values `1`, `2`, for each item to be a unique string instead, say `location1`, `location2`?

Comment: You're using $indexnew, which is a counter and is why you're getting 1, 2, etc. Instead of $indexnew, use whatever you want. eg. $locations['location_1'] = array("image_link" => ....)